# SharePoint Online - Basic Search Center and Custom Masterpage "Code Blocks are not allowed in this file"?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, master-page

I have a Site Collection with a subsite of a Basic Search Center. I have a custom masterpage applied to all subsites, including the Search Center.

My problem is, when I try to go to the Basic Search Center subsite, it says to me "Code Blocks are not allowed in this file". This happens for both `default.aspx` and `results.aspx`.

Is there a way that I can avoid this error? A workaround I have found is to enable Publishing Features and create a Page that simulates the look and feel of the `results.aspx` but I'm looking if there is an easier way.

Comment: The Basic Search site does not use Publishing, the Enterprise Search Site does.

Comment: Thanks Matthew! That works! Can you post as a reply so I can mark as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Basic Search site does not use Publishing Features. Use the Enterprise Search site as it uses Publishing and generally provides a better end user experience.